# Detecting Same Questions at Different StackExchange Sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, duplicate-questions

Sometimes there maybe same questions (exactly same questions) at different StackExchange sites. I know they should be moved to correct site but is there any daemon or machine learning development at StackExchange side that tries to detect same(or similar) questions towards different Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 2):

> is there any daemon or machine learning development at StackExchange side that tries to detect same(or similar) questions towards different Stack Exchange sites?

No, there isn't, at least not at the moment. There may be plans to change this if it becomes a real problem. It is rare enough that it probably doesn't merit action.

And remember, that often, Stack Exchange users do use several sites and may very well identify such duplicates and flag them as cross-posts to the moderators so they can take appropriate action. This is enough of a working solution at the moment.

Comment: How to detect such questions cross posted at different sites?

Comment: @Tilak - Are you asking about users or a automated way?

Comment: automated way. Also, if there is a way user can link questions, it is  also useful

Comment: @Tilak - Well, simple text comparison should do. The sites are in different databases and this will probably require some background job, but it is possible. The main issues are architectural rather than one of identifying the same text (or similar - using the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)).